# Azure AKS restrict the use of a specific IP

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-virtual-network

We have to setup an Ingress Controller and the process requires us to assign a specific IP Address based on available IP in our Subnet. It works the first time we created an AKS and then setup the Ingress Controller. However, when we recreate the AKS, the IP we assigned to Ingress was used by one of the VMSS instance.

Is there a way for us to restrict an IP from being used in AKS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that the AKS assigns the IP addresses in the subnet dynamically. So you can't control it. Usually, AKS assigns the IP addresses from the first available IP address "x.x.x.4" to the last "x.x.x.254". So maybe you can choose the IP address for the Ingress Controller from the last one.

There is one thing you need to pay attention to. That is you need to calculate the number of the IP address that you need to use for the AKS cluster. If you have too many nodes, then maybe there will no available IP address left. So make sure the subnet has enough IP address to use.